# Show children and hide the parents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a  `.folder` when its clicked and hide all the rest of the content. Just like a file browser.

Comment: Can I ask why you can't simply use a file browser?  If you're interacting with the user's hard drive, you should have the IO classes available to display a simple file browser.

Comment: Not interacting with user's hard drive at all. Listing files from server side.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ what's not working?

Comment: What's wrong with it? http://jsfiddle.net/M9nhP/

Comment: Edit : Okay I understood the question now. never mind then. Like Spokey said.

Comment: Deleted the comment by mistake. But from what I understood he wants to hide the parent '#yepo' (or it's other children) and show only the clicked child `.folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ul li.folder').on('click',function(e){

    $(this).siblings('li').toggle();
    $(this).children().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the jQuery [`siblings()` selector.](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('.folder').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).children().toggle();
    $(this).siblings('li.folder').children().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: this almost works perfectly but not for 2/3/4.. level deep list's

Comment: Play around with it.  Maybe you need to use some other selectors (.parent()?  .children()?  What behavior are you seeing that isn't as intended?  Try things, it's fun.

Answer (score 0):

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/M9nhP/4/)

```
//toggle children and siblings
$('.folder').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).children().toggle();
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
//cancel file clicks
$('.file').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```